# How to apply p-value for each group of dataframe in R using facet_wrap in ggpubr

Tags: r, anova

I have a data that looks like this:

```
melted.df <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("24", 
"36", "48", "72"), class = "factor"), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), Samples = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("WT_Ago2_800", "WT_Ago2_400", "WT_Ago2_200", 
"WT_Ago4_800"), class = "factor"), Size = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.3, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.65, 0.2, 0.85, 0.725, 0.575, 0.1, 1.1, 0.9, 
1.325, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 2.2, 1.65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.825, 1.175, 
0.1, 0.55, 0.85, 0.85, 1.1, 1.4, 0.6, 0.95, 1.15, 0.975, 2.35, 
1.15, 2.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.65, 1.4, 0.55, 0.1, 0.7, 1.1, 
0.95, 1.85, 0.85, 0.1, 1.5, 1.25, 1.8, 1.75, 2.15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-84L), class = "data.frame")
```

This data consists of 4 time frames (24, 36, 48 and 72 hours). I want to use the code below to paste the p values calculated as `stat.test` for each `time.levels` and apply that to each `facet_wrap`. If you check for i=1, there is no p-value so it's nothing you would want to apply to the figure, and if you do i=2, you would get p-values applied to the figure. The problem is that I couldn't get the p-value applied to its respective facets. It just applies same p-value in all facets. How can I get this resolved?

code:

```
library(devtools)
# install_github("https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix")
library(rstatix)  # https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix
library(stringi)
library(ggpubr)
time.levels <- levels(melted.df$Time)
stat.test <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(time.levels)){
  stat.test <- aov(Size ~ Samples, data = melted.df[melted.df$Time == time.levels[i],]) %>%
  tukey_hsd()
# stat.test <- rbind(stat.test, tmp.stat)
 bp <-  ggboxplot(melted.df, x = "Samples", y = "Size") +
    facet_wrap(vars(Time))+
    stat_pvalue_manual(
      stat.test, label = "p.adj",
      y.position = c(2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3.8, 4)
    )
 bp

}
```

Comment: Don't you need two loops; one for storing `stat.test` and one then one for plotting?

Comment: @M-M Not sure about that

Comment: Looking at the answer, that's what I meant! You only plotted for `i = length(time.levels)` (maybe typo of *one then one* made my comment unclear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note. All your values in Size for `Time == 24L` are zero:

```r
> filter(melted.df, Time == 24L) %>% select(Size) %>% summary
      Size  
 Min.   :0  
 1st Qu.:0  
 Median :0  
 Mean   :0  
 3rd Qu.:0  
 Max.   :0
```

If you wish to proceed anyway, you should make the plots individually and then use `gridExtra::grid.arrange`:

```r
library(gridExtra)
bp <- vector("list", length = length(time.levels))
for (i in seq_along(time.levels)) {
  sdf <- melted.df[melted.df$Time == time.levels[i],]
  stat.test <- aov(Size ~ Samples, data = sdf) %>%
      tukey_hsd()

 bp[[i]] <-  ggboxplot(sdf, x = "Samples", y = "Size") +
    facet_wrap(vars(Time))+
    stat_pvalue_manual(
      stat.test, label = "p.adj",
      y.position = c(2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3.8, 4)
    )
}
do.call(grid.arrange, bp)
```

**Note** that you have to use the subset `data.frame` `sdf` as the input for `ggboxplot`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.

Here is a clean solution.

```
library(rstatix) # latest version
library(ggpubr)  # latest version
stat.test <- melted.df %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  tukey_hsd(Size ~ Samples)

ggboxplot(melted.df, x = "Samples", y = "Size", facet.by = "Time") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(
    stat.test, label = "p.adj",
    y.position = c(2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3.8, 4)
  )
```